# Pass KS Test Fail Z Score Test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, z-score, z-test

Im working with some messy data and was comparing two data sets. I used both the KS test and the Z-Score
I found instances where Means would be found to be different under the Z score test but the distributions would be the same under the KS test.
Can anyone provide some theoretical reasons why this may have occurred. I probably violated an assumption of the tests at some point but I'm pretty unfamiliar with the KS test

Comment: The KS test never allows you to conclude distributions are the "same:" you can only conclude it has not detected a *difference* to your satisfaction.  Note, too, that sometimes the KS test is not conducted correctly (such as when data are compared to a reference distribution that was estimated from the same data): it's therefore important that you explain how you applied it.

Comment: Sure in reference to how I applied it: Data sets were indeed from different populations but had the same variables e.g. height. I found that the Z score of the two populations had the same height, however the heights had different distributions under KS. I'm not exactly sure what you mean by reference distribution unfortunately

Comment: @randomUser The “reference distribution” has to do with a one-sample test, while yours is a two-sample test. // Your comment seems to contradict your post. The comment says that KS flagged the distributions as different, while your post says that KS missed this.

Comment: @Dave I misspoke in my comment to whuber

Comment: 1. I shudder at the inappropriately normative terms "pass" and "fail" in relation to hypothesis tests. Please stick to "reject" and "not reject". $\:$   2. It's easy for a test of equality of means to have a different outcome of a test of equality of distributions, even when all the assumptions of both hold, since they test different things. Note that the KS test spreads its power more thinly across a much broader class of alternatives, so it should be expected to have less power against the more specific alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KS is a general test of distribution equality, capable of detecting lots of differences (means, variances, etc) but not specializing in any in particular.

Z is a specialist, better than KS at detecting differences in mean but incapable of detecting much else.

By analogy, all you did was have Dr. KS refer you to a specialist.

**EDIT**

Note that “passing” a hypothesis test is nonsense. Hypothesis tests result in “reject” and “fail to reject”, not “reject” and “accept”. I suspect you know this and just were loose with the terminology, but it’s important to sort out in your head why the two are different.

Comment: So what you're saying is in this case, to use the medical analogy; Dr. KS is the primary care physician who didn't see anything unusual, but Dr.Z who specializes in this body part found something abnormal?

Comment: Precisely! Physicians are better than this analogy suggests, but you’re getting the statistics.

Comment: Thank you Dave!